# ROBLOX - How do I run my code at the same time as this?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a script in ServerScriptService and I do a 60 second countdown while the game is happening:

```
for i = 60, 0, -1 do
    status.Value = "Game: "..i
    wait(1)
end
```

How do I run the game's code at the same time? In lua you apparently can't at the same time so what do I do? How do I run the game's code while it's happening?

I tried this:

```
while true do
    while wait(0.1) do
        if (spawnCheese and #cheeseTable < 100) then
                local c = cheese:Clone()
                c.Parent = workspace
                local spacing = 2
                c.Position = Vector3.new(math.random(-spawnArea.Size.X/spacing,spawnArea.Size.X/spacing),2, math.random(-spawnArea.Size.Z/spacing, spawnArea.Size.Z/spacing))
                table.insert(cheeseTable, c)
                collectCheese(c)
        end
    end     
end
```

but it only runs for one frame before or after the countdown.

Answer (score 0):

Either use 'coroutine' or 'spawn' function to run the countdown part of your code. You can find out more about threading on Roblox documentation website.